# What is the difference, if any, between the work of the Holy Spirit in our lives vs. the apostles lives?

Tags: pneumatology, spiritual-gifts, apostles

I think all Christian denominations will agree as fundamental doctrine that the Holy Spirit was sent to us (the invisible church) after Christ's death on the cross (John 14:16). However, it seems like there might be a difference in the way the Holy Spirit was meant to work in the apostles' lives as opposed to ours.

For example: The gospel of John says:

> But the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I have said to you. -John 14:26

How can the Holy Spirit remind us of things we've never heard before? It seems that this statement in particular was specifically addressing the disciples who were there in the room with Jesus at the time. This "reminder" then helped the disciples write the New Testament. We, on the other hand, aren't blessed with this specific gift, as we aren't called to write the Bible. Instead it seems the job of the Holy Spirit in our lives is to help us bear good spiritual fruit (Galatians 5:22-23).

Is this a correct conclusion? What do you all think? Are there any other differences you can think of or do you think the giving of the Holy Spirit was functionally the same in both cases?

God Bless!

Comment: Any reason for the protestantism tag? In the Catholic Church, the Holy Spirit still uses people to make sure that His teaching is preserved.

Comment: You are correct :). I just kind of default to adding the tag, but it's removed now and I welcome any/all answers!

Comment: Which Apostles? there were more than 12.  And what about the 70? there is no difference.

Comment: What are the 70? And for this question, I guess I'm referring to those apostles present in John 20:22, for arguments sake.

Answer (score 1):

The Holy Spirit can still remind us of what Christ has said to his apostles in the Gospels, as well as what through the epistles and in Revelation. You may wonder what good that may be, but the answer is: Plenty! When you are talking to people, you don't always have time to scour your Bible for answers. If you are well read in the Bible, the Holy Spirit could bring to mind verses that you have read.

I think the Holy Spirit does the same kind of works today as he did back then, to those who are open to allow Him to work in their lives with free reign.

Answer (score 1):

> Joh 14:12  Verily, verily, I say unto you, He that believeth on me, the works that I do shall he do also; and greater works than these shall he do; because I go unto my Father. 
>   Joh 14:13  And whatsoever ye shall ask in my name, that will I do, that the Father may be glorified in the Son. 
>   Joh 14:14  If ye shall ask any thing in my name, I will do it. 
>   Joh 14:15  If ye love me, keep my commandments.
>
> 1Co 12:1  Now concerning spiritual gifts, brethren, I would not have you ignorant.

...

> 1Co 12:7  But the manifestation of the Spirit is given to every man to profit withal. 
>   1Co 12:8  For to one is given by the Spirit the word of wisdom; to another the word of knowledge by the same Spirit; 
>   1Co 12:9  To another faith by the same Spirit; to another the gifts of healing by the same Spirit; 
>   1Co 12:10  To another the working of miracles; to another prophecy; to another discerning of spirits; to another divers kinds of tongues; to another the interpretation of tongues: 
>   1Co 12:11  But all these worketh that one and the selfsame Spirit, dividing to every man severally as he will.
>
> 1Co 12:28  And God hath set some in the church, first apostles, secondarily prophets, thirdly teachers, after that miracles, then gifts of healings, helps, governments, diversities of tongues. 
>   1Co 12:29  Are all apostles? are all prophets? are all teachers? are all workers of miracles? 
>   1Co 12:30  Have all the gifts of healing? do all speak with tongues? do all interpret?
>
> 1Co 13:13  And now abideth faith, hope, charity, these three; but the greatest of these is charity.

This is from a Word of Faith Bible literalist perspective. We will not write a new Bible but besides that everything recorded in the word of God done by ministers and lay people is equally available for ministers and lay people today. Every spiritual gift which is wrought by the Holy Spirit in the apostles of the first church is still in operation for the apostles of the current generations church who have faith. The word of God never declares an end to the gifts till knowledge itself passes away.